# Using Solr as a data source for Solr with DIH

Tags: solr

Currently, our Solr indexing is really slow using DIH grabbing data from MySQL. It uses sub-entities and the sheer amount of queries is leading to constantly old data in Solr.

I was thinking about breaking up these 3 queries into their own cores and then using the "flatter" cores with DIH to issue Solr queries via the http API to build an aggregated core.

Anybody know if thats possible or feasible?

We are using Solr 6.6.6

Comment: Any option to optimize the queries and entity handling instead? Do you need to query them as sub entities? If you can get them out from the three different cores; could  you perform a JOIN and to the lifting in a single SQL statement instead?

Answer (score 0):

If you have decided to break them up into 3 queries and if you can run them in parallel with no problem then you might as well have 3 data import files and run them in parallel to the same Solr collection.

You really don't have to have 3 collections and then a combined collection. You can save a lot of time and material.

```
  <requestHandler name="/dataimport" class="solr.DataImportHandler">
    <lst name="defaults">
      <str name="config">db-data-config-part1.xml</str>
    </lst>
    <lst name="defaults">
      <str name="config">db-data-config-part2.xml</str>
    </lst>
    <lst name="defaults">
      <str name="config">db-data-config-part3.xml</str>
    </lst>
  </requestHandler>
```